# Can we check the state of microphone of an android phone, if we can then how can I do this

Tags: android, microphone

I want to write a program to check if the internal microphone of android phone is on, off or in use by some other application.

If this is possible then how can I do this?

I read related questions at stack overflow but did not find a solution.

Comment: What related quesions did you find? And what is different in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is *no way* to know the microphone's state (Busy, Available,..). Sorry

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I'm using to **check if the microphone is busy** (based on Odaym answer and my own tests):

(**Updated** with Android 6.0 Marshmallow compatibility, as suggested in comments)

```
  public static boolean checkIfMicrophoneIsBusy(Context ctx){
        AudioRecord audio = null;
        boolean ready = true;
        try{
            int baseSampleRate = 44100;
            int channel = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
            int format = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
            int buffSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(baseSampleRate, channel, format );
            audio = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, baseSampleRate, channel, format, buffSize );
            audio.startRecording();
            short buffer[] = new short[buffSize];
            int audioStatus = audio.read(buffer, 0, buffSize);

            if(audioStatus == AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION || audioStatus == AudioRecord.STATE_UNINITIALIZED /* For Android 6.0 */)
                ready = false;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            ready = false;
        }
        finally {
            try{
                audio.release();
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
        }

        return ready;
    }
```

Comment: For Android 6.0 audioStatus will be `AudioRecord.STATE_UNINITIALIZED`  if mic is busy. So edit your code to `if(audioStatus == AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION || audioStatus == AudioRecord.STATE_UNINITIALIZED)`

Comment: I don't think `STATE_UNINITIALIZED` can be returned by `AudioRecord.read`, only by `getState`. Not sure how to find out if the mic is busy on Android 6

Comment: It takes around 500ms to check this

Comment: it's too slow, isn't not good for dashcam apps

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an `AudioRecord` object to record audio, like:

```
AudioRecord audio = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
Constants.SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,Constants.BUFFER_SIZE_BYTES);

audio.startRecording();
```

Then right after `audio.startRecording()`, you're going to have to provide a buffer for reading the audio data into, and begin reading. You do that with:

```
int audioStatus = audio.read(bufferObject, 0, bufferSize);
```

The [Android documentation for read()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) mentions the return value `ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION` (*Constant Value: -3*), this is only returned when the Mic is busy so you can check for that in your code and show a message that the Audio source is busy with another app.

Comment: For Android 6.0 audioStatus will be `AudioRecord.STATE_UNINITIALIZED` if mic is busy. So edit your code to `if(audioStatus == AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION || audioStatus == AudioRecord.STATE_UNINITIALIZED)`